# Location of postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf on an Ubuntu server

Tags: postgresql, configuration

Where are the files `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` on a Linux server running PostgreSQL 8.4 installed from Ubuntu repos?

Comment: The problem is b/w the chair and the keyboard. It depends on how you installed it. Did you use source tar-gz file or did you use apt utility. If you download tar-gzipped file and installed it. The pg_hba.conf file does not exist yet unless you initialize your data directory. The INSTALL/Readme file has that info. You will find pg_hba.conf file in whatever you selected as your data directory.

Secondly, if you used apt utility then you should find it in /etc/postgresql/8.4/main


you can also do a 'find' on the filename but doing that on the entire disk is cpu-consuming.

Comment: Installing from source to the default install location, you run the following: /usr/local/pgsql/bin/initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data before starting postgres and hba file will be created in that directory.

Comment: in kubuntu v20.04 i used `sudo updatedb ` and `sudo locate pg_hba.conf`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looking for "pg_hba.conf ubuntu" on Google gives you

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL

which shows the location of the files.

The documentation states the following:

> Client authentication is controlled by
>   a configuration file, which
>   traditionally is named pg_hba.conf and
>   is stored in the database cluster's
>   data directory. (HBA stands for
>   host-based authentication.) A default
>   pg_hba.conf file is installed when the
>   data directory is initialized by
>   initdb. It is possible to place the
>   authentication configuration file
>   elsewhere, however; see the hba_file
>   configuration parameter.

Note it says **stored in the database cluster's data directory** and that it's possible to place it elsewhere, via a configuration parameter. Official documentation cannot point you to a specific folder because the actual location depends on both how the OS maker and the machine's administrator have set PostgreSQL up. Remember PostgreSQL supports a lot of different operating systems (and Linux distributions.)

As [Neutrino shows](https://serverfault.com/a/877213/1619), if you can access your server via psql, you can tell it to show you the file location.

Also, two tips:

1. locate will help you find files you know the name of but not the location
2. Debian based distributions place under /usr/share/doc documentation on how they set up different packages by default, I'm sure you'll find under /usr/share/doc/postgresql-8.4 (or maybe just postgresql) info about the configuration files. Very useful to read in case they have modified some standard behavior.

Comment: Give a man a fish... blah blah, teach a man how to fish.. etc. The right way is to know how to have postgres tell you where the file is. Universally. `show hba_file;
` in psql. See @neutrino's answer.

Comment: If and only if you can access your running PostgreSQL instance. If your HBA file is messed up you might not be able to. I've linked to Neutrino's answer.

Comment: How to find it at the remote server then?

Answer (score 30):

Open a command prompt.

```
> psql -U postgres
=# show hba_file;
=# show config_file
```

When they change the names of the config settings, or you want to see something else.

```
=# show all;
```

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work if you can't start your pgsql database because of a "missing" `postgresql.conf`! It's "missing" because it's not located in `/var/lib/postgresql/<VERSION>/<CLUSTER_NAME>` on Ubuntu, but as someone else pointed out, in `/etc/postgresql/<VERSION>/<CLUSTER_NAME>`. Why does Ubuntu have to be different from everybody else? Ugh..... And because of this, simply issuing `sudo -u postgres pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgres/<VERSION>/<CLUSTER_NAME>` results in an error because the `postgresql.conf` file is not found. Geez. :/

Comment: And as I learned from @milen-a-radev answer, the docs say that the `-D` option value _really_ needs to be set to where the `postgresql.conf` file is located. That option should be renamed to `-C` (for `--configuration`) since it doesn't _really_ need to be set to the data directory--which on most _normal_ distros _happens_ to be the (default) location of the `postgresql.conf` file, but not always (glaring at you Ubuntu....).

Answer (score 5):

Possibly

```
/etc/postgresql/9.*/main
```

Answer (score 4):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-file-locations.html

Comment: As always, RTF(riendly)M. This is the _right_ answer. _Assuming_ that Ubuntu did things "normally", results in `pg_ctl` complaining that the `postgresql.conf` file cannot be found in the "data" directory as specified by the `-D` option to the `pg_ctl` command. Perhaps that option is a bit "mis-named" since it must point to where the `postgresql.conf` file is located, which on Ubuntu is in the `/etc/postgres` directory...of course. Ugh. I hate Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

As Vinko said, the location is distribution-dependent. To add to his answer:

Your package management sofware will tell you where are the files installed by each package, (for example: `dpkg -L postgresql`).

You can also look inside the service startup script ( typically `/etc/init.d/postgresql`)

Answer (score 2):

To see the configuration files from the terminal:

```
psql -U postgres -c 'SHOW hba_file'
psql -U postgres -c 'SHOW config_file'
```

To check the data directory:

```
echo $PGDATA
```

or

```
psql -U postgres -c 'SHOW data_directory'
```